# Python module not found Azure function app

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Python application to an Azure Function App via Azure DevOps.

In my build pipeline I can see that it successfully installs the required package Pygresql from my requirements.txt in the root folder of the project, but then I get a module not found message when I deploy to the app in Azure.

[image: Build pipeline success message]
Please find my build pipeline configuration below:

```
pool:
name: Azure Pipelines

trigger:
branches:
    include:
    - master
    
steps:
- bash: |
  if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
  then
      dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
  fi
 displayName: 'Build extensions'

 - task: UsePythonVersion@0
   displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'
 inputs:
   versionSpec: 3.7

 - script: |
    python -m venv worker_venv
    source worker_venv/bin/activate
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install setuptools
    pip install setup
    pip install -r requirements.txt
 displayName: 'Install Application Dependencies'

 - task: ArchiveFiles@2
 displayName: 'Archive files'
 inputs:
   rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
   includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Miles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The ways to fix the module not found error:**

#### Way 1

Specify your python version in your Script portion

```py
.
.
.
# either you can use script / bash. Here i am using bash
 - bash: |
    python3.7 -m venv worker_venv
    source worker_venv/bin/activate
    python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip3.7 install setuptools
    pip3.7 install setup
    pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt
 displayName: 'Install Application Dependencies'
.
.
.
```

Refer [build CI/CD for python azure functions using Azure DevOps](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-build-ci-cd-for-python-azure-functions-using-azure-devops-7087a76e535b)

#### Way 2

Instead of using `pip install -r requirements.txt` try using below

```py
# for python version 3.7
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

# for python version 3.6
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
```

Refer [example yaml build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core,yaml,python#example-yaml-build-pipelines) using python azure function.

#### Way 3

Instead of using `python -m venv worker_venv` try using `python -m venv .python_packages`

Refer the [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/708#issuecomment-765528255) for information.

Comment: I've tried all three of these methods and they haven't worked sadly, please see my code below, also please note i'm using classic pipelines for the deploy stage if that affects it.

Comment: displayName: 'Build extensions'
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7' 

- bash: |
   python3.7 -m venv .python_packages
   source worker_venv/bin/activate
   python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
   pip3.7 install setuptools
   pip3.7 install setup
   pip3.7 install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install Application Dependencies'